# Have been vs Was

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

> 1. I **have been** brought up  in London.

> 2. I **was** brought up in London

what is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: 1 is perhaps intended to imply something related to the present, 2 is just the pure past!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "I was there" and "I have been there"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18124/what-is-the-difference-between-i-was-there-and-i-have-been-there)

Answer (score -1):

The first is odd. Normally ‘have been’ is used for repeated actions: “I have been to London twice”. This means that at this time I am in the state of having been there twice.

It is used less often for a state of being, again usually for more than one thing: “I have been a nurse and a missionary, I now do construction.”

However it is not used for a one time past continuous event like ‘brought up’. Much better ‘was’.