# Using present perfect with for after the event ended with for

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I had an English exam about two days ago, and one of the questions was

**My uncle ____(live) in Alexandria for 20 years. Now, he lives in Cairo**

what I answered is
Has Lived.
EDIT: The model answer is "Lived"
is this grammatically correct, or just plain wrong
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question in present perfect, but answer in past simple. Why not a past simple question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/312540/question-in-present-perfect-but-answer-in-past-simple-why-not-a-past-simple-qu)

Comment: _My uncle has lived in Alexandria for 20 years_ is a correct sentence, but not appropriate here because it implies that he still lives there.

Comment: Connecting: He *lived* there in the past, and *lives* now in Cairo.

Comment: No, I don't think that answers my question, i specified it a bit more, my question is if it is possible to use the present perfect with "For" while the even already finished ig he doesn't live there anymore

Comment: So, @KateBunting does that mean it is grammatically correct?, and if so should it be classified as a "Wrong Answer" that's what I am trying to achieve, if you have any proof it's grammaticly correct, please I would be grateful

Comment: _He has lived there for X years_ (and still does). _He lived there for X years_ (but now lives somewhere else). The model answer is correct, and you can't use the present perfect with a period of time if the situation is no longer ongoing.

Comment: There are *some* contexts where you can use Present Perfect ***have lived** [somewhere]* even if you no longer live there. For example, *I have lived abroad for much of my life because of my job, but I retired to Sussex last year*. Which would also be fine using Simple Past *I **lived** abroad...*, but the Perfect version *slightly* draws more attention to some "connection" between those two phases of my life (the "connection", being *me*, if nothing else! :)

Comment: "Has lived" would mean that he is still there, but the following sentence contradicts that, so it doesn't make logical sense.  "Has lived" is fully grammatical, but in this particular context it's not correct to use it here. The correct answer is "lived". 
Tense choice is always dependent on context.

Answer (score 0):

There is no grammatical reason why the answer you gave should not be a valid one. The only reason the official answer is better is because of the *meaning*. This is why tests are often hard; you're forced to choose among several valid options and decide which is the most *likely* one.

The example sets up a contrast; the uncle *used* to live in Alexandria, and *now* he lives in Cairo. Present perfect is often used for actions that are "ongoing." "I've been a grocer for 20 years" implies that I still am one. So it would be an odd choice for this example. But if the example were just "My uncle has lived in Alexandria for 20 years"—and he still does—then there's no problem. Or if he now has two houses:

> "My uncle lived in Alexandria for 20 years. Now, he *also* lives in Cairo."

There are even other tenses that would be grammatical but unlikely. How about the future tense!

> "My uncle *will live* in Alexandria for 20 years. Now, he lives in Cairo."

This time there isn't even a conflict in the meaning. This is just an unlikely thing to say because we don't normally plan how long we live in a city. But the same tenses and construction might be fine for a different situation:

> "Soon I will study for 20 minutes. But for now, I eat."